# WebDriver Error: invalid argument: missing 'ELEMENT' (Session info: chrome=120.0.6099.129) typescript identify shadow element inside iframe

Tags: typescript, google-chrome, webdriver, ui-automation

I have a function to enter some text in a text box, the text box element is like below

```
<rich-text-editor _ngcontent-qaa-c309="" fd-form-control="" formcontrolname="description" show-list-group="" show-link-group="" show-text-group="" origami="" class="text-editor ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid" aria-label="" aria-labelledby="fd-form-label-2" sap-rich-text-editor=""></rich-text-editor>
  <iframe id="ui5wc_1_ifr" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" title="Rich Text Area" class="tox-edit-area__iframe" srcdoc="<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta http-equiv=&quot;Content-Type&quot; content=&quot;text/html; charset=UTF-8&quot; /></head><body id=&quot;tinymce&quot; class=&quot;mce-content-body &quot; data-id=&quot;ui5wc_1&quot; aria-label=&quot;Rich Text Area. Press ALT-0 for help.&quot;><br></body></html>"></iframe>
```

```
  async enterDescription(descriptionText) {
    const shadowEle = await $(`rich-text-editor`).shadow$('#ui5wc_1_ifr.tox-edit-area__iframe');
    await browser.switchToFrame(shadowEle);
    await $('body').setValue(descriptionText);
    await browser.switchToParentFrame();
  }
```

then it goes to setValue, i got the error of **WebDriver Error: invalid argument: missing 'ELEMENT'**
any insight on how to resolve it? when my chrome version was having lower version like 114, it is working fine, since upgrade to 119, it starts to broken